# mongodb using $pop in subdocment

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Struggling with the use of $pop in a mongodb. Suppose I have the following collection:

```
`{_id:3
  name: "item 1",
  subdoc:{
            array:[
                     {id: "999",
                      name:"bar"
                     },
                     {id: "777",
                      name:"foo-bar"
                     }
                  ],
            anotherproperty: "foo"
         }
}`
```

Given it's id, I would like to remove an item from subdoc.array.

So for the document above, how can I remove the item with id="999", so that the only remaining item in subdoc.array would be the one with id="777"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$pop`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) operator removes the **first** or **last** element of an array. Pass `$pop` a value of `-1` to remove the first element of an array and 1 to remove the last element in an array.

I think it is better to use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to do it

```
> db.docs.update({name: 'item 1'}, {$pull: {'subdoc.array': {'id': '999'}}})
```